# Como obter resultado da query separado por colunas?

Tags: php, sparql

Preciso fazer uma consulta na dbpedia e a partir dessa consulta retornar nome, gênero e outras informações de um determinado cantor. Eu estou conseguindo fazer isso, porém meu código retorna a tupla toda, queria poder separar as informações por coluna. Alguém pode me ajudar?
Segue o código:

```
<?php
    require_once('sparqllib.php');
    $db = sparql_connect('http://dbpedia.org/sparql');
    $query = "  PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
                PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
                PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
                PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
                PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
                PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
                PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
                PREFIX dbpedia2: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
                PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/>
                PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
                PREFIX owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
                PREFIX rsc: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
                    SELECT ?name ?hometown ?origin ?genre ?bandMember ?currentMembers ?associatedMusicalArtist
                    WHERE { 
                      rsc:Arctic_Monkeys dbpedia2:name ?name.
                      rsc:Arctic_Monkeys owl:hometown ?hometown.
                      rsc:Arctic_Monkeys dbpedia2:origin ?origin .
                      rsc:Arctic_Monkeys dbpedia2:currentMembers ?currentMembers .
                      rsc:Arctic_Monkeys owl:genre ?genre .
                      rsc:Arctic_Monkeys owl:bandMember ?bandMember .
                      rsc:Arctic_Monkeys owl:associatedMusicalArtist ?associatedMusicalArtist .

                    FILTER ((LANG(?name) = 'en') AND (LANG(?origin) = 'en')).
                    }";

    $result = sparql_query($query);
    $fields = sparql_field_array($result);
    while($row = sparql_fetch_array($result))
    {
      foreach($fields as $field)
      {
        print"$row[$field] \n";
      }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Se refere a isso?

echo $row['name']." ( ".$row['origin']." ) <br/>";

Comment: Isso mesmo Dalton! Porém fiz o teste trocando "print"$row[$field] \n";" por "print"$row['name'] \n";" e não funcionou... =/
deu o erro "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING"

Comment: experimente assim: `print $row[$field]."<br>\n";` (com ou sem o `<br>`, dependendo do resultado desejado). Alternativamente, assim: `print $field.': '.$row[$field]."<br>\n";`

Answer (score 1):

Basta printar a coluna por seu respectivo índice.

```
print ( $row['name']."\n".$row['origin'] );
```

Não sei no Linux, mas no Windows para o `\n` quebrar a linha, precisa-se da função `nl2br`.

Ficando:

```
print nl2br( ( $row['name']."\n".$row['origin'] ) );
```

Answer (score -1):

Que tal tentar com o [Freebase.com](https://www.freebase.com/)?

{
"id": null,
"name": "Arctic Monkeys",
"type": "/music/artist"
}

O Freebase também usa dados da Wikipedia e todas requisições são em JSON, assim é fácil pedir qualquer informação específica.

Comment: Caso o resultado do DBPedia seja um "array"=>"associativo" basta adicionar foreach($fields as $key=>$value)

Comment: desculpe gaucho, mas não entendi a solução... poderia dar esse exemplo utilizando o campo name que é retornado da query? obrigado!